# How can I add numbers instead of combining them in a string?

Tags: javascript

If I use this code it makes from an number an string but I can't figure out why.

I want that this program adds 8+9 and makes = 17 not 89.

I try to learn this for as a hobby but I tried this almost a year ago and when I got stuck I never tried to make it work till now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Variables</h2>

<p id="demo_totaal"></p>
<p id="uitkomst1">8</p>
<p id="uitkomst2">9</p>

<script>

var a = document.getElementById("uitkomst1").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("uitkomst2").innerHTML;
var total = a + b;
document.getElementById("demo_totaal").innerHTML = total;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change your strings to numbers `parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)` should work as you expect. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("uitkomst1").innerHTML` returns the string, so your result will be a string of two strings added together.

You need to convert the string to a number if you want to add two numbers. Javascript has different ways to do this.

In your case, it should use the Number class to convert. I think it is the best option because it can convert decimal numbers too.

```
var numberA = new Number(a); // "8.1"
var numberB = new Number(b); // "9.1"
var total = numberA  + numberA ; // 17.2
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, you can use `parseInt(string)` to do that. Like,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Variables</h2>

<p id="demo_totaal"></p>
<p id="uitkomst1">8</p>
<p id="uitkomst2">9</p>

<script>
var a = document.getElementById("uitkomst1").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("uitkomst2").innerHTML;
var total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
document.getElementById("demo_totaal").innerHTML = total;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure user input don't have any decimals, else it will removed in `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to do this using parseInt/parseFloat/new Number. See other answers for this.

I use this mostly, multiply the number or string with 1 and then do addition. So far I havent seen any issues. Performance I am not sure though

```
var total = a*1 + b*1;
```

```js
var a = "1";
var b = "12.5";

var total = a*1 + b*1;

console.log(total)
```